# Rails order by count based on values of column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, count, querying

`Rails 5.1.2`

I have a two models `Student` and `Award` this way:

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :awards
end

class Award < Application Record
  belongs_to :students

  # Categories
  scope :attendance, -> { where(category: 0) }
  #...(other award categories)
  scope :talent,     -> { where(category: 8) }
  # Ranks
  # Gold
  scope :rank_1, -> { where(rank: 1) }
  # Silver
  scope :rank_2, -> { where(rank: 2) }
  # Bronze
  scope :rank_3, -> { where(rank: 3) }
end
```

`Award` has these columns: `rank` and `category`.

Now, I want to get the top student for a given category. The criteria for this is, order by count of "gold" awards (rank `1`), then order by count of "silver" (rank `2`) awards, and then order by count of "bronze" (rank `3`) awards.

So, if I were to get the `Student` who meets the top criteria for category `0` (which is handled by the `attendance` scope as described in the model above), this is what I thought the query should look like:

```
Student.joins(:awards).where(awards: { category: 0 }).group('students.id').order('COUNT(awards.rank == 1) DESC', 'COUNT(awards.rank == 2) DESC', 'COUNT(awards.rank == 3) DESC').take
```

However, this returns the Student with the highest count of awards, regardless of rank. So for example, if I remove `take`, the order looks like this:

```
# |St.ID | Gold  | Slvr. | Brnz. |
----------------------------------
1 |  12  |   4   |   12  |   8   |
----------------------------------
2 |   1  |   9   |   0   |   4   |
----------------------------------
3 |   6  |   9   |   1   |   0   |
----------------------------------
4 |  18  |   5   |   2   |   2   |
----------------------------------
 ...
```

So, the order I'm getting are IDs `12, 1, 6, 18, ...`, when it should be IDs `6, 1, 18, 12, ...`.

I realize the `order('COUNT(awards.rank == 1) DESC', 'COUNT(awards.rank == 2) DESC', 'COUNT(awards.rank == 3) DESC')` part is simply ordering by the count of awards total (rather than count of a awards with a particular value in column `rank`).

I can easily solve this by adding a counter cache for each category of awards, but that isn't an elegant nor flexible solution.

As a bonus, after this query returns a successful result, I will search the database again to find all students who have the same score (as there could be ties). I'm not aware of a way to do all this in one query (perhaps by means of subqueries after getting the values for each rank).

Comment: Did you try `.order('COUNT(awards.student_id) DESC').order('COUNT(awards.rank == 1)').order( 'COUNT(awards.rank == 2)').order('COUNT(awards.rank == 3)')`

Comment: Tried it just now; got the same result. I don't think the order of the student's ID matters though.

Comment: my bad, I didn't mean to add student_id

Comment: @user2985898 Tried it; couldn't do a single query. Let's wait for someone who knows better in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be the double equal??

EDIT: This is a more proper way (Assuming MySQL):

```
 Student.joins(:awards).where(awards: { category: 0 }).group('students.id').order('COUNT(if(awards.rank = 1)) DESC', 'COUNT(if(awards.rank = 2)) DESC', 'COUNT(if(awards.rank = 3)) DESC').take
```

First try your code without it, if that doesn't work, you might want to try this:

```
SELECT students.id, gold, silver, bronze) FROM students 
JOIN ON 
  (SELECT students.id as id COUNT(awards) as bronze
  FROM students JOIN awards ON students.id = awards.student_id
  WHERE awards.rank = 1
  GROUP BY students.id) q1 q1.id = students.id
JOIN ON 
  (SELECT students.id as id COUNT(awards) as silver
  FROM students JOIN awards ON students.id = awards.student_id
  WHERE awards.rank = 2
  GROUP BY students.id) q2 q2.id = students.id
JOIN ON 
  (SELECT students.id as id COUNT(awards) as gold
  FROM students JOIN awards ON students.id = awards.student_id
  WHERE awards.rank = 3
  GROUP BY students.id) q3 q3.id = students.id
ORDER BY gold, silver, bronze
```

Comment: I've done it with both = and == with the same result. I'll try your solution when I get a chance.

Comment: I'm using SQLite for development and MySQL for production.

Comment: I'm 100% sure the COUNT(property = value) doesn't work in MySQL, and I think it doesn't work in SQLite either. If the IF syntax doesn't work for you in SQLite, the one that should work for sure is:
    SUM(IF(students.awards = 1, 1, 0))
I'm pretty sure that's where your problem lies. (You should be able to check if Gold is actually giving back the proper results)

Also, quick suggestion: Use MySQL locally as well, it may be more of a pain to set it up, but the amount of times that different syntax screw me when pushing to production is uncanny.